# It's possible to use Sass to define <form>,<a> etc.. with bootstrap styles, instead of using classes?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

I would like to know if there is any easy way to add the styles of boostrap directly to the elements like forms, tables, links, etc instead of using classes.

For example, the primary button is : btn btn-primary.

I would like that styles directly at `<button>`, and then if I would like to change that style, I could add the secondary class like `<button class="btn-secondary">`

Same for form-control, etc..

Do you know if this is possible without changing 1000 variables in their sass? Or there is an easy way to achieve this?